# 2 Different Background Colours For ScrollView bounce

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a `ScrollView` that has a top section with one background colour and a bottom section with another different colour.

When a user scrolls past the content and the view bounces (elastic over-extend), how could I make it so the background is consistent with either the top or the bottom, depending on the scroll direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On iOS, you can render a spacer `View` on top of the `ScrollView`, and use `contentInset` to render it "off-screen", `contentOffset` to set the initial scroll position to offset the inset:

```
render() {
  const isIos = Platform.OS === 'ios'
  const SPACER_SIZE = 1000; //arbitrary size
  const TOP_COLOR = 'white';
  const BOTTOM_COLOR = 'papayawhip';
  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{backgroundColor: isIos ? BOTTOM_COLOR : TOP_COLOR }}
      contentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: TOP_COLOR}}
      contentInset={{top: -SPACER_SIZE}}
      contentOffset={{y: SPACER_SIZE}}>

      {isIos && <View style={{height: SPACER_SIZE}} />}
      //...your content here

    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Because `contentInset` and `contentOffset` are **iOS only**, this example is conditioned to degrade gracefully on Android.

Comment: hey is there any way to change the color of the scrollbar or scroll indicator that appears on right side of the list. in case of verticle scrolling ?

Comment: I may have spoke too soon… this only works on iOS. I had to condition this solution to only apply on iOS.

Comment: This solution did not work so well for me due to insets/offsets messing up with my contentContainerStyle flexGrow 1 => the content did not grow properly. Check this other solution which is perhaps easier to apply into multiple places: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597156/82609

Comment: This is a horrible solution

Answer (score 40):

I wouldn't play with the `contentInset` and `contentOffset` of the ScrollView as if your content changes, it might change the position of your scrollview.

You can do something very simple by just adding a View at the very top of your ScrollView:

```
// const spacerHeight = 1000;

<ScrollView>
  {Platform.OS === 'ios' && (
    <View 
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: spacerHeight,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -spacerHeight,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
      }} 
    />
  )}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Much simpler, thank you. I tried this after implementing the accepted answer and this feels much better. The accepted answer inexplicably caused some of my content inside the ScrollView to disappear. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: As a huge added bonus with this method, you can put content in the bounce area (in my case I added a gradient. It looks so nice).

Comment: Although, this does not work with the RefreshControl when used with FlatList?

Comment: Beware that this absolute view will cover up the refresh indicator... I ended up putting it on the bottom instead

Comment: simply amazing you save my day thanks

Comment: @GregT What do you mean by "on the bottom instead"? What's the difference in code between your version and the version in this answer?

Comment: @alexander This was years ago, but I set "bottom: -spacerHeight" rather than top. It was interfering with the refresh indicator. If you don't set refreshControl on your ScrollView then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @GregT Yeah I know! Thanks for answering anyway! I ended up using `zIndex: 1` for the `RefreshControl`

Answer (score 12):

The accepted solution did not work well for me because I need to put `flexGrow: 1` on the contentContainerStyle. Using insets/offsets didn't make the content grow the way I want, otherwise it worked not so bad.

I have another solution to suggest: putting a bicolor background layer under a transparent ScrollView, and add colors to your scrollview content. This way, on ios bounce, the bicolor layer under the scrollview will reveal itself.

Here's what I mean by bicolor layer (here the scrollview is empty and transparent)

[image]

Now if I put back the ScrollView children (which if a body with blank background, and a footer with yellow background), I get this:

[image]

As long as you don't bounce more than 50% of the scrollview height, you will see the appropriate background color.

Here's a component you can use to wrap your scrollview.

```
const AppScrollViewIOSBounceColorsWrapper = ({
  topBounceColor,
  bottomBounceColor,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <View {...props} style={[{ position: 'relative' }, props.style]}>
      {children}
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: -1, // appear under the scrollview
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: topBounceColor }}
        />
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: bottomBounceColor }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And here's how you use it:

```
  <AppScrollViewIOSBounceColorsWrapper
    style={{flex: 1}}
    topBounceColor="white"
    bottomBounceColor="yellowLancey"
  >
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WhiteBackgroundBody/>
      <YellowBackgroundFooter />
    </AppScrollView>
  </AppScrollViewIOSBounceColorsWrapper>
```

Make sure to NOT set a background color to the scrollview, otherwise the bicolor layer will never reveal itself (backgroundColor on contentContainerStyle is fine)

Comment: this is fantastic, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

This is, I think the most stupid simple way i found to do it:

```
<ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: '#000000'}}>
  [...]
  <View style={{position: "absolute", bottom: -600, left: 0, right: 0, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', height: 600}}/>
</ScrollView>
```

You may adjust the height/bottom absolute value to your likings depending on how far you think the user could scroll.

I personally implemented that into a `<ScrollBottom color={"white"}/>` component for ease of use in all my ScrollViews

Answer (score 4):

For me, the simplest solution is modification based on [Sebastien Lorber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366080/2-different-background-colours-for-scrollview-bounce#:%7E:text=%E2%80%93%C2%A0-,Sebastien%20Lorber,-Aug%2021%20%2719) answer which doesn't include wrapping, just calling it before (or after) ScrollView component:

Create component:

```
interface IScrollViewBackgroundLayer {
  topBounceColor: string;
  bottomBounceColor: string;
}

export const ScrollViewBackgroundLayer = ({
  topBounceColor,
  bottomBounceColor,
}: IScrollViewBackgroundLayer): ReactElement => (
  <View
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      zIndex: -1, // appear under the scrollview
    }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: topBounceColor }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: bottomBounceColor }} />
  </View>
);
```

and use it like this:

```
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollViewBackgroundLayer topBounceColor={topBounceColor} bottomBounceColor={bottomBounceColor} />
      <ScrollView>
       ...
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: This is simple and elegant. Thank you.